# I need to find the minimum value for a large dataframe that will group by site (location of the facility) and for a rolling previous 12 months period

Tags: python, min

The dataframe looks like:

```
   site     desc        unit    date            amount 
1  site a   metric1     lbs     10/31/2018      13.00 
2  site a   metric1     lbs     9/30/2018       12.00 
3  site a   metric1     lbs     8/31/2018       16.00 
4  site a   metric1     lbs     7/31/2018       19.00 
5  site a   metric1     lbs     6/30/2018       11.00 
6  site a   metric1     lbs     5/31/2018       13.50 
7  site a   metric1     lbs     4/30/2018       13.00 
8  site a   metric1     lbs     3/31/2018       12.00 
9  site a   metric1     lbs     2/28/2018       16.00 
10 site a   metric1     lbs     1/31/2018       19.00 
11 site a   metric1     lbs     12/31/2017      11.00 
12 site a   metric1     lbs     11/30/2017      13.50 
13 site a   metric1     lbs     10/31/2017      13.50
```

I would like to find the min value for each site for a 12 month date range:
for site a from 11/30/2017 to 10/31/2018 the min would be 11.00.
for site a from 10/31/2017 to 9/30/2018 the min would be 11.00.
This will go back to about 2013 data by month.  I would like to do this with Python since the window frame I tried in SQL can't do MIN without unbounded preceding which blows the 12 month range.

Comment: ... That's not a dataframe. That's HTML.

Comment: Yes I needed to represent it in the question, tried to clean it up using HTML tags.

Comment: Oh man, that was a lot of wasted effort :/ drop the HTML, copy/paste `.head()` (or similar), highlight it all, and click the `{}` button in the editor, or press `ctrl` + `k` :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a site where we can help with code you are writing. It's not often that someone will just write a large program for you. Please get started with the solution you want to build and come back when you need help. Then post the code and what part you need help with.

Answer (score -1):

This can totally be done in SQL:

```
SELECT site, MIN(amount)
FROM YourDataSource
WHERE date BETWEEN '11/30/2017' AND '10/31/2018'
GROUP BY site
```

Comment: Sorry yes this part can be done in SQL.  As stated in the original post wanted to to this rolling back the the first entries in the data.  So this would have to go back to around 2013.

Comment: Think of it like a window around the data that starts at the current date and looks back across that last 12 entries to find the minimum, then for the previous date it does the same thing for the previous 12 entries and so on to the beginning of the data set.

Comment: Ok, so you need a for loop and an array to store your minimums as you go. You feed the dates in to the SQL query and save the result in your array.